# How to truncate zalgo text when copying from postgres

Tags: amazon-s3, zalgo

I'm copying data from postgres into s3 and a field has zalgo text which causes downstream jobs to fail. How can I truncate it properly? It becomes too long when copying it into a table and I'm not sure what to do?

```
    SELECT...
substring(caption for 2000) as caption,
```

that's how I'm copying the zalgo text but that is stored as an insanely long string in s3. What am I doing wrong?